# Bind xamarin grid with datatable

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to bind Grid with DataTable. I searched but could not find any sample for this.

Some data will be populating a DataTable and I want to show that in the Grid.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms does not have this control built in. You will need to use a third party resource like https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/data-grid

Comment: @AndresCastro Any alternative to do this? As of now I am using binding with ListView.

Comment: Use ListView and build the grid as item

Comment: @FabriBertani I have done exactly what you suggested. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it. The only limitation with ListView is that it is not easy to edit existing items as in DataTable and no way to define Primary Key.